# Getting the overall lighthouse score in an automated way

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I'm trying to automate getting the score for a number of different pages. But the api doesn't seem to provide the overall score, like the web version does.

I've tried using the Lighthouse API v5 and v4, neither seemed to have the score, I may have missed it. I got it to work by using puppeteer on the pagespeed insights site, but that's since stopped working, and want to check I haven't missed anything before I try and fix it again

Answer (score 3):

The returned JSON has a section under `lighthouseResult` called `categories`.

Within `categories` you will see `performance` and then `score` is a child there with the score out of 1 (so a score of 89 would be 0.89).

```
"lighthouseResult": {
......
    "categories": {
        "performance": {
            "id": "performance",
            "title": "Performance",
            "score": 1.00, <- here is the score.
            "auditRefs":
......
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be having some issues with your setup. Try to run it via chromium, following works fine for me:

Install chromium and lighthouse:

```
sudo install --y chromium-browser
sudo npm install -g lighthouse
lighthouse --output-path=./Production-lighthouse-report.html URL
```

Script to run Lighthouse Tests on the desired URL via headless chrome:

```
lighthouse --chrome-flags="--headless" --output-path=./Production-lighthouse-report.html URL
```

Comment: That provides a score for the four categories, not the overall score. Which is the one that I need